# How can I force a user to login with a specific Microsoft account?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a use case where I want someone to login with their Microsoft account in order to get a token for the Graph API.

For my specific use case I would like the user to be forced to login with one specific account in case they have more than one.
Is there a way to force this with the login URL?
For now the only thing I found is changing the `common` in the URL to the tenant GUID, this results in an error "*You cannot access this right now*" if the user selects an account in another tenant. It would be better if the user can't even choose another one, even one in the same tenant.

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` → `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantGuid}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

I'd like to able to include the user GUID to the URL or the email like "person@company.com" for example but I didn't find anything like that being possible, is this correct?

Also, the prompt I selected for the login screen was `&prompt=consent` because the user needs to consent to the permissions again, as a requirement on our end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

By adding `&login_hint=person@company.com` I can force the screen to auto select the right account.